# How to generate an iOS framework from Python library

Tags: python, ios

I want to create a new iOS application which uses a library written in Python. I want to know how I can to generate an iOS framework from Python library.

Or if this is not possible, do you have any other idea to achieve this? This Python library is a dependency for my application.

Comment: You can try PyMob maybe?

Comment: "PyMob™ is a technology which allows developers to create mobile apps in Python!"
I don't want to write my app in Python. I just want to convert that Python library in iOS. I can convert only the library with PyMob and write the rest of the app natively?